# rendering JSON data to HTML tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, foreach

I am trying to get a huge json file into a HTML table. But I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: v.forEach is not a function` error. What am I doing wrong?

My JSON:

```
{
"data": {
    "goog": {
        "calls": [
            {
                "bv": {
                    "fatal": [
                        "xyz"
                    ],
                    "notice": [
                        "v35",
                        "abc"
                    ],
                    "syntax": [],
                    "warning": [
                        "pto"
                    ]
                },
                "data": {
                    "lmc": "9",
                    "aid": "a103",
                    "as": "2"
                },
                "result": {
                    "fatal": [
                        "theFatal"
                    ],
                    "notice": [
                        "notice1",
                        "notice2"
                    ],
                    "syntax": [],
                    "warning": [
                        "warning1"
                    ]
                },
                "url": "https://www.google.com",
                "validated": false,
                "vendor": "AA"
            }, 
            "data": {
    "goog": {
        "calls": [
            {
                "bv": {
                    "fatal": [
                        "xyz"
                    ],
                    "notice": [
                        "v35",
                        "abc"
                    ],
                    "syntax": [],
                    "warning": [
                        "pto"
                    ]
                },
                "data": {
                    "lmc": "9",
                    "aid": "a103",
                    "as": "2"
                },
                "result": {
                    "fatal": [
                        "theFatal"
                    ],
                    "notice": [
                        "notice1",
                        "notice2"
                    ],
                    "syntax": [],
                    "warning": [
                        "warning1"
                    ]
                },
                "url": "https://www.google.com",
                "validated": false,
                "vendor": "AA"
            }
    }
```

My code:

```
let api_url = `api?ar=${run_id}`;
console.log(api_url);

$.getJSON(api_url, function(data) {
  console.log(data);

  Object.values(data).forEach(d => {
    console.log(d);
    $.each(d.goog, function(k,v) {
      v.forEach((x,y) => {
        console.log(x);
      });
    });
  });
```

For now I am only trying to view a lot of my data in the console. I need to get all this data in a table. Is there another easy way to do this? What Am I missing.

For now my code is returning the values but also giving me the `Uncaught TypeError: v.forEach is not a function` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, with your last comment, I manage to understand what I assumed from the beginning.

Your problem is that the last value is not an array, but an object so it does not have `forEach` method  (as the error states)

This is your last value before the error is shown. You can clearly see that it is an object:

`{ "fatal":14,"notice":14,"syntax":0,"warning":2 }`

You can solve your problem by checking if is an array like this:

```
Object.values(data).forEach(d => {
    console.log(d);
    $.each(d.goog, function(k, v) {
        if(Array.isArray(v) { // <--- HERE checks if value is an array.
            v.forEach((x, y) => {
                console.log(x);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This way you avoid calling forEach on non array values.

Comment: have I told you that you are my favorite javascript person of all time? I bow to thee!

Comment: @newbierp This has nothing to do with jQuery. I would recommend you to not use jQuery at all. JavaScript has evolved very much.

Comment: Got it. I changed my comment!

Comment: Can you please help with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255783/includes-is-not-finding-the-last-value-in-the-table